# Hydro - groovy - indigo

Tags: rosdep, ros-groovy, ros-indigo, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I made `rosdep update`, it says :

```
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Ignore legacy gbpdistro "groovy"
Ignore legacy gbpdistro "hydro"
Query rosdistro index https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
Add distro "groovy"
Add distro "hydro"
Add distro "indigo"
updated cache in /home/lempereur/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
```

Is this in error, that it add distro "groovy", "hydro" "indigo"?
I'm using groovy (Ubuntu 12.04)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187518/hydro---groovy---indigo/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No it's not an error I'm using `Hydro` and I get the same shell as you, don't worry.

They are not installed on your system but It's kind of knowing other distributions.

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-23**:
Thank you!!!